# branch less float comparison in HLSL

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

Is there a way to rewrite `value = 1; if(x > y) value = 0;` (where value, x, and y are all floats) without using branches? I have seen a solution for integers but I cannot find one for floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lerp` for this purpose, in your example it would be `value = lerp(1.0f, 0.0f, x > y)`. This is, by the way, exactly what the shader compiler will do automatically when flattening a branch - whether or not a branch gets flattened is another topic, see the attributes `[flatten]` and `[branch]`.